# How do I control which linked Components are published when I publish a specific Component?

Tags: tridion

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. I have Components A, B and C. Component C is linked with A & B.

If I publish C, both Component A and B are getting published. But I want only Component A to be published.

Can any one explain how to exclude Component B from publishing?

Answer (score 10):

What you are experiencing is the default behaviour of Tridion. This is by design, to ensure that when you change content in a component, publishing it will update all instances of that content on the website.

As the other answers suggest you can change this behaviour using a Custom Resolver:

```cs
 using Tridion.ContentManager;
 using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
 using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
 using Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing;
 using Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving;

public class UpdateResolvedItems : IResolver
{
      public void Resolve(
            IdentifiableObject item, 
            ResolveInstruction instruction,
            PublishContext context, 
            Tridion.Collections.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems)
      {
           foreach (ResolvedItem resolvedItem in resolvedItems)
           {
             // Check resolved items, and remove accordingly
           }
      }
}
```

The code example above demonstrates you can get access to a collection called resolvedItems. This is a list of items due to be published, unless you make a change to it.

You can iterate through this list and remove items according to your requirements.

Answer (score 8):

So far I know there is no easy way to do this. When you publish one item Tridion resolves all the related and linked items and publishes them.

You can use event system or a custom resolver to achive want you are asking.
This link might help:
http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/10/tridion-publisher-and-custom-resolvers.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are publishing from API you can set `IncludeComponentLinks` property of `ResolveInstruction` to `false`, or, as Bappi pointed do this in the event handler

Comment: He could, but that would mean that just Component C would be published. When publishing Component C he wants Component A to also get published, but not Component B. A resolver is the only way to accomplish that I think.